# Searching object arrays and index positions

Tags: java, arrays, object, search, indexing

Got the original problem solved. Anyone any ideas how to retrieve both the object that I want as well as its index position? Saving the index position to use within the main.

```
//==========================================================================================
                 //SEARCH FOR USER
public User find(String searchName)     
{
  int j;
  for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)           
     if(a[j].getLast().equals(searchName))      
        break;                  
  if(j==nElems)             
     return null;               
  else
     return a[j];               
} // end find
//===========================================================================================

  public static void main(String[] args){
  int maxSize = 100;            
  ClassDataArray arr;           
  arr = new ClassDataArray(maxSize);    

  arr.insert("Evans", "Patty", 24);         
  arr.insert("Smith", "Tom", 59);
  arr.insert("Smith", "Lorraine", 37);

  arr.find("");
 }
```

Comment: `nElems` is zero always that's why `j==nElems` is true and returns `null`

Comment: [This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) Specifically, we need to see the code you use to populate the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is than `nElems` is set to `0`, not `max`.

Change:

```
nElems = 0;
```

to:

```
nElems = max;
```

Comment: You realize every element in the OP's array is null right? Presumably because OP is using a "dynamic" array. That's the only explanation I can see for `nElems` being tracked separately from `max`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch He hasn't shown us the code where the array gets populated. Honestly, the lack of that method makes this question impossible to answer. But I'm not the one who downvoted your answer... but he didn't say he was getting a `NullPointerException`, he said it wasn't returning anything, which is why your answer is not likely to be his problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's very possible `null` checks are unnecessary if he checks for `null` appropriately in the methods that populate the array.

Answer (score 0):

You set your nElems to 0 `nElems = 0;` but` but didn't change it later. So j will never be smaller than nElems.